# 11db error in c++; Xcode.

Tags: c++, c, debugging, timer

I am just starting out in c/c++ and I tend to get this error frequently. Sometimes I can just type c into the console and the program will continue just fine. but other times it will not, like in the case of this code.

I'm trying to create a simple timer/stopwatch that shows the amount of seconds passed when the program begins. I'm trying to control it's on or off state dependent on if a variable is 1 or 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    int onoff = 1;

    if (onoff == 1)
    {
        int timex = 0;
        while (onoff < 1)
        {
            timex++;
            printf("time: %d", timex);
            sleep(1000);
        }
    } 
    else if (onoff == 0)
    {
        char timex[] = "off";
        printf("the timer is %s", timex);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe I just need to figure out how to debug? If that is the case, is there anywhere I can look to learn how to debug efficiently?

Comment: I don't use Xcode so I don't know what the `11db` error you are talking about is.  But a basic compiler can figure out that this code does nothing and just return 0. Check your conditions for `onoff`.

Comment: You want a `sleep()` of 1000 seconds?

Comment: It's [LLDB](http://lldb.llvm.org), with L's, not 1's.  What about showing the error?!

Comment: Looked for a Spinal Tap joke and found nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Use Boolean variables for `true`/`false`, on / off or any two state variable, which makes your program easier to read.  Also, rename your variable.

```
int main()
{
  bool timer_on = true;
  if (timer_on)
  {
    int timex = 0;
    while (timer_on)
    {
      ++timex;
      cout << "time: " << timex << "\n";  // Since you supplied the C++ tag.
      sleep(10000);  // This is a platform or RTOS specific function.
    }
  }
  else if (timer_off)
  {
    cout << "The timer is " << timex << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

One issue is that you define `timex` inside the *then* portion of the `if` statement and that is not accessible to code inside the `else` portion.

You are missing a final `else` clause to your `if-else if` ladder.  Maybe you wanted something like:

```
  else
  {
    if (!timer_on)
    {
    }
  }
```

or maybe that inner `if` is not necessary because the code will execute in the `else` statement if the timer_on is `false`.